# Postreg SQL get All Value with quotes from the comma separated

Tags: sql, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have Values which are stored like `1,2,3,4,5` in the database.

I want it back like `'1','2','3','4','5'`.

I am trying with  `string_agg(format('''%s''', ticker_information.user_groups), ',')`
but giving me result `'1,2,3,4,5'`

Any solution ? Or let me know If I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Don't store your relational data as CSV.  Fix your design, and your current question might even not be relevant anymore.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Actually It a stored already by the previous developer. And we cant change the schema now. Its a Live..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you just want a string back with the quotes

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3,4,5'::text as test
)

SELECT
  '''' || array_to_string(
    string_to_array(test, ','),
    ''','''
  ) || ''''
FROM sample
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array from your csv string using `unnest`, wrap the elements with `quote_literal()` and then aggregate them again. You can achieve this with a subquery ..

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(i),',') FROM 
  (SELECT quote_literal(unnest(string_to_array(user_groups,','))) 
   FROM ticker_information) j (i);

   array_to_string   
---------------------
 '1','2','3','4','5'
```

Or with a `LATERAL` :

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(quote_literal(j.i)),',') 
FROM ticker_information, 
LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(user_groups,',')) j (i);

  array_to_string
---------------------
'1','2','3','4','5'
```

Another option would be with regular expressions.. but it could get nasty if the elements of your csv contain commas.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bd255b17de109c58c1fad67e1db979e4)